# HOG people detection and changes in size due to perspective

Tags: opencv

I am trying to make HOG work for people detection using OpenCV. My problem is that the persons in my application appear in different sizes due to perspective, so, I am afraid I have to train different people sizes. Here are my questions:
 1.- I already have INRIA and MIT databases. all images are 128x64 pix. Could I resize that database to have bigger and smaller samples and later train the system several times? 2.- Will I obtain different lenghts in HOG descriptors if the images in tha database are of different size?

Finally, my negative database is very different in samples to the situation I am facing. I want to detect people in an industrial environment ( machines, repair shop, etc) and the samples are of cities, streets, beaches, etc. Is this negative databa useful? or could I detect only people and reject directly low matches?

Thank you all very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that the persons in my application appear in different sizes due to perspective

You can use [gpu::HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html#gpu-hogdescriptor-detectmultiscale)

> Is this negative databa useful? or could I detect only people and reject directly low matches?

All negative data is useful, the more data you train with the more robust your system. However if you are only using one use case. I would suggest getting some background images of the environment you are going to be using it in.

Comment: Thank you for your incredible fast response.
gpu::HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale

is not working properly, is it possible to train for example 3 classifiers and use detect multiscale with all of them?